# expressjs route methods before and after

Tags: node.js, express

How to add middleware functions to each of expressjs route functions ? Most of route functions which turn out to be CRUD on database have standard before and after statements - is there a way to have before and after for route functions.

```
  app.route('/api/resources').all(projectsPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(resources.list)
    .post(resources.create);
```

Comment: Do you mean like `app.use(projectsPolicy.isAllowed)` etc ?

Comment: app.use functions are called for all functions in route, am I right ? Im looking for somethign that can be called for each route function

Comment: I guess that depends on the middleware, but I believe you can do `app.route('/api/resources', projectsPolicy.isAllowed).get(...`, multiple functions are allowed in Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible to make this:

```
app.route('/api/resources').all(projectsPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(before,resources.list,after)
.post(before,resources.create,after);
```

where before and after are functions

Comment: Thank you - its possible - app.get('/example/c', [cb0, cb1, cb2]); - documentation example(http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Express supports multiple callbacks, as in

```
app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
   // do something here, like modify req or res, and then go on

   next();
}, function (req, res) {

   // get modified values here

});
```

which could also be written as

```
app.route('/api/resources', projectsPolicy.isAllowed).get(...
```

assuming the middlewares `isAllowed()` function calls `next()` etc.